# Redis Authentication is required

Tags: docker-compose, redis

I have this python code for Redis Docker container:

```
pool = ConnectionPool(host='redis_db', port=6379, db=0)
redis_db = Redis(connection_pool=pool, password='redis')

redis_db = Redis(host='redis_db', port=6379, db=0, password='redis')
```

If I use the first variant works without container, but when I run Redis in Docker container it fails with the error "Authentication is required". And when I use the second variant everything works fine. What's the difference between this 2 variants?